# How to parse with a delimiter

Tags: c, string

I have a line with the following format:

```
str="WORD1\tWORD2\tWORD3\tWORD4...";
```

The thing is that I need to get the third word.

I have been playing around with strchr and strcpy but I am only making a mess.

The only thing that I want to do is to save in the very same string variable str so I can keep on parsing until the third column.

```
char *p;
p=strchr(str,'\t');
strcpy(str,str,p?);
```

I would appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to safety parse tab-delimiter string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839664/how-to-safety-parse-tab-delimiter-string)

Comment: char *p;  
p=strchr(str,'\t');
p=strchr(p+1,'\t');
p=strchr(p+1,'\t');
And thats without doing any error checking.
strchr will return a pointer to the next occurence of needle or NULL if it reaches the end of the string, hence you need to increment the pointer to search for another '\t'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay, this is how I finally implemented it:

```
      int main() 
      {

          char *readbuff="WORD1\tWORD2\tWORD3\tWORD4...";
          char * pch;
          int third_col=0;
          pch = strtok (readbuff," \t");
          while ((pch != NULL)&& (TRUE == notfound))
          {
            pch = strtok (NULL, " \t");
            if (third_col==1)
            {
              dprintf (DBG_INFO,"The third word is: %s\n",pch);
              notfound=FALSE;
            }
            third_col++;
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, Just an **idea** (I didn't check for other strings):

Code doesn't give word for first and last, It only output substring if its parenthised by `\t` as you required.:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
    char* str="WORD1\tWORD2\tWORD3\tWORD4";
    char *p1 = NULL;
    char *p2 = NULL;
    int i = 0, which = 3;
    char word[10]={0};

    scanf("%d", &which );
    p1 = str;
    for(i=0 ; (p1 != NULL) && (i < which-1); i++){
        p1=strchr(p1 + 1, '\t');
        if(p1 +1)
        p2=strchr(p1 + 1, '\t');
    }

    if(p1!=NULL && p2!=NULL){
        strncpy(word, p1, p2-p1);
        printf("\n %s\n", word);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

it runs like:

```
$ ./a.out 
1
:~$ gcc x.c
:~$ ./a.out 
2
    WORD2
:~$ ./a.out 
3
    WORD3
:~$ ./a.out 
4
```

Is it what you need ?

Comment: That was very helpful. I will post in a couple hours the solution I have used.

Answer (score 0):

There are

```
strpbrk()
strspn()
strtok()
strsep()  // define _BSD_SOURCE to have this available
```

available to do parsing.

---

Also you could use regular expression by calling `regcomp()` and `regexec()`.

Answer (score 0):

**(1)**

`strchr` will locate first occurrence of character in string ([man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr)).

```
char *strchr(const char *s, int c);
```

**(2)**

`strcpy` copies the string pointed by source into the array pointed by destination ([man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy)).

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);
```

**(3)**

You need to use `strtok` to parse your input string ([man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok)).

```
char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim);
```

See an example: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

**(4)**

You can't copy a string into non allocated pointer. You need to allocate memory to your destination.

**(5)**

Here is a sample code that explain you more:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char *str="WORD1\tWORD2\tWORD3\tWORD4...";
    char *p = NULL;
    char *out = NULL;
    int count = 0;
    int needed = 2; 

    p = strtok(str , "\t");
    while(p && count != needed) {
        p = strtok(NULL , "\t");
        count ++;
    }

    if(p) {
        out = malloc(strlen(p) + 1);
        strcpy(out, p);
        printf("String found: %s\n", out);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have solved it with a very similar approach. I will post it when the time restriction is finished.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *cut(int nth, char* out, const char* in){
    const char *pi=in;
    char *po=out;
    int n = 0;
    for(;;){
        *po=*pi;
        if(*po=='\t')
            *po='\0';
        if(*po == '\0'){
            ++n;
            if(n==nth)
                return out;
            else if(*pi == '\0')break;
            po=out;
        } else 
            ++po;
        ++pi;
    }
    return NULL;
}
/*
int main() {
    const char *str="WORD1\tWORD2\tWORD3\tWORD4\tWORD5";
    char word[32]={0};
    printf("%s\n", cut(3, word, str));//WORD3
    return 0;
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple c++ piece of code :

```
    string s = "abc\tdef\tghi";
    stringstream ss(s);
    string a,b,c;
    ss >> a ; ss.ignore() ; ss >> b ; ss.ignore() ; ss >> c;    
    cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << endl;
```

Output :

```
abc def ghi
```